# Element of a Set randomly changing

Tags: java, set

For some reason one of the elements of Set s are changing randomly without my code altering it at any point. Not sure why the Set changes from:

[[red, green], [green, red], [red, red], [green, green]]

to

[[green, red], [green, red], [red, red], [green, green]]

for no reason.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Fermat {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> colours = new HashSet<String>();
    colours.add("red");
    colours.add("green");
    analyse(threadings(2, colours));
}

public static Set<ArrayList<String>> threadings(int n, Set<String> s) {
    Set<ArrayList<String>> combos = new HashSet<ArrayList<String>>();
    if (n < 0) {
        combos.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        return combos;
    } else {
        int[] index = new int[s.size()];
        do {
            ArrayList<String> newCombo = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                newCombo.add(s.toArray(new String[s.size()])[index[i]]);
            }
            combos.add(newCombo);
            index[index.length - 1]++;
            for (int i = (index.length - 1); i > 0; i--) {
                if (index[i] >= s.size()) {
                    index[i] = 0;
                    index[i - 1]++;
                }
            }
        } while (index[0] < s.size());
        return combos;
    }
}

public static boolean isEquiv(ArrayList<String> a, ArrayList<String> b) {
    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

            if (a.equals(b)) {
                return true;
            }

            Collections.rotate(a, 1);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public static void analyse(Set<ArrayList<String>> s) {
    Set<ArrayList<String>> singletons = new HashSet<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> combos = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    for (ArrayList<String> combo : s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        if (singleton(combo, s)) {
            singletons.add(combo);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(singletons);
}

public static boolean singleton(ArrayList<String> c, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cs.size(); i++) {
        {
            if (isEquiv(c, cs.get(i)) && !c.equals(cs.get(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: I just changed `if (singleton(combo, combos)) {
    singletons.add(combo);
   }` and the result is [[red, green], [green, red], [red, red], [green, green]]

Comment: what is the sense of `Collections.rotate(a, 1);` in `isEquiv` method?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. `analyse` calls `singleton` with a Set as the second parameter, but it takes an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mutating the lists with `Collections.rotate(a, 1)`. In this case it ends up rotating that `[red, green]` to `[green, red]` at some point, and that affects every reference to that list object.

You need to create a new list and rotate that, so the original list object isn't changed. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<>(a);
for (int i = 0; i < a2.size(); i++) {

    if (a2.equals(b)) {
        return true;
    }

    Collections.rotate(a2, 1);
}
```

Comment: Specifically:  rotating a List (or changing a List in any way) alters its hashCode, so the hash codes kept by the HashSet are no longer valid for the Lists it contains.